# Como modifico el Title de la Home en blogger

Tags: html, blogger

buenos dias. Quiero que me ayuden a modificar el titulo de la Home de mi blog para tener un mejor SEO cuando se busca en google.

**Por ejemplo:**

Mi blog se llama: Stackoverflow y quiero poner la Home:

**Stackoverflow | Blod de Programadores**

Pero no se que como tengo que modificar el title de blogger

```
<title><data:view.title.escaped/></title>
```

Yo le puso a la etiqueta `<title><data:view.title.escaped/> | Blod de Programadores</title>`  Pero me sale "Blod de Programadores" en todos lados y yo quiero que se vea solo en la home. Creo que falta agregar una condicional, pero no se como agregarlo.

Answer (score 2):

1. Haz una copia de seguridad de tu plantilla:  "Plantilla > Crear/Restablecer copia de seguirdad"
2. Edita la plantilla: "Plantilla > Editar HTML"
3. Localiza esta línea de código: CTRL+F

y sustitúyela por este código:

```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
  <title><data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
  <title><data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if>
```

4. Guarda la plantilla y visualiza los resultados

Comment: Hola Luis, dime en que parte le tengo que poner "Blod de Programadores" para que en las búsquedas me salga el titulo como yo quiero. Es decir primero el nombre del nombre que en este caso es Stackoverflow y la parte que yo le quiero agregar Blod de Programadores

 Stackoverflow | Blod de Programadores

Comment: La ayuda que buscaba ya la conseguí, pero la dejo por aqui

<title><data:view.title.escaped/><b:eval expr='data:view.isHomepage ? " - Blod de Programadores" : ""'/></title>